# Java Design pattern: Avoid Duplication of code for Azure Rest api call

Tags: java, design-patterns, azure-web-app-service

I have written a small java program which will make a rest call and it works fine as expected. I would. Now, I have to write a similar program for other API calls. How do, I structure the code so that, I can avoid duplicating the code!!

```
System.out.println( "Usage Details!" );

AzureProfile profile = new AzureProfile(AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
TokenCredential credential = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder()           
       .authorityHost(profile.getEnvironment()
                             .getActiveDirectoryEndpoint())
       .build();
ConsumptionManager consumptionManager = ConsumptionManager.authenticate(credential, profile);

// the below detail changes for different api's
PagedIterable<UsageDetail> usageDetailList = consumptionManager.usageDetails()
        .list("url",<argument1>,<argument2>,null,null,Metrictype.USAGE,Context.NONE);
int count=1;

for(UsageDetail usageDetail : usageDetailList){
        LegacyUsageDetail legacyUsageDetail = (LegacyUsageDetail)usageDetail.innerModel();
        try{
            //if(legacyUsageDetail.date().toString().equals("2021-09-22T00:00Z") && 
                 legacyUsageDetail.resourceGroup().startsWith("F2BDEVC-ms")){
                if(count==1){
                    System.out.println("subscriptionName : " + 
                           legacyUsageDetail.subscriptionName());
                  }}
  }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Java SDK to call Azure rest API. The Azure SDK for Java libraries build on top of the underlying Azure REST API, allowing you to use those APIs through familiar Java paradigms.

To use Azure Java SDK to call Azure rest API first you need to create a service principal (SP). Then install the SDK as show below -

```java
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
    <version>1.33.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then write the code similar to the one show below.

```java
private static String tenantId=""; // sp tenant
private static String clientId = ""; // sp appid
private static String clientKey = "";// sp password
private static String subscriptionId=""; //sp subscription id

ApplicationTokenCredentials creds = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId,tenantId,clientKey, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);

RestClient restClient =new RestClient.Builder()
                .withBaseUrl(AzureEnvironment.AZURE, AzureEnvironment.Endpoint.RESOURCE_MANAGER)
                .withSerializerAdapter(new AzureJacksonAdapter())
                .withReadTimeout(150, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .withLogLevel(LogLevel.BODY)
                .withResponseBuilderFactory(new AzureResponseBuilder.Factory())
                .withCredentials(creds)
                .build();
OkHttpClient httpClient = restClient.httpClient().newBuilder().build();
String url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/"+subscriptionId+"/providers/Microsoft.Migrate/projects?api-version=2018-02-02";
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                              .url(url)
                              .method("get",null)
                              .build();
Response response1 = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();

if(response1.isSuccessful()){
        System.out.println(response1.headers().toString());
}
```

For more information on design guidelines check this [Java Azure SDK Design Guidelines](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/java_introduction.html).